# Is there a keyboard shortcut to enable/disable hidden files in Finder?

Tags: keyboard, finder, high-sierra, macos

Is there an easy way to show and then hide and then show and then hide (as in toggle) “hidden” files in macOS High Sierra?

I’ve found I can use the following terminal commands to show them:

```
 defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

killall Finder

and then use these terminal commands to hide them:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
```

killall Finder

but this is **clumsy**!

I then came across [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) which allows me to do this at will, but unless I want to keep it open, it’s not a good option because it takes forever to launch!

I did check the list of keyboard shortcuts at [this Apple website](https://support.apple.com/HT201236) in the hope it may be that simple, but no go.

What is the absolute easiest way to enable/disable this option? If there's no keyboard shortcut, what's the next best option?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Actually, there is a keyboard shortcut you can use in macOS High Sierra. More specifically, you can use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

In case that last key isn’t clear, it’s a period (aka full stop).

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate how you came across that shortcut? ("Teach a man to fish...")

Comment: @FooBar Good question! Unfortunately, I can't remember for the life of me where I first came across it. All I can tell you is that it was in December some time (I remember that because it was just before Christmas and I've been using the shortcut ever since!). Sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: This is so cool. What a time saver!!